# Similarity between a heart attack and a spasm

Tags: physiology, cardiology, muscles, electrophysiology, pathophysiology

When someone is having a heart attack, could it be considered , in some situations, a spasm? Below, I have written how I believe the process may work.

The heart is basically a muscle working constantly to create a sinus rhythm. As I understand it, one can get muscle spasms in any muscle (correct me if I'm wrong). If so, then couldn't someone get a muscle spasm in a part of the heart muscle that disrupts the sinus rhythm and causes chaotic signals? Thus causing a spasm throughout the muscle.

When one is having a heart attack, does the electric shock used cause a dramatic and fast 'stretching' of the heart muscles allowing the heart to get over the spasm and back to normal rhythm? Could something else, like an ElectroMagnetic Pulse be used to 'stretch' the heart muscles away from the spasms?

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate a bit here? Are asking what kind of damage could be done by this happening? From what I understand, a dramatically fast stretching of the heart could do serious damage to it; but I'll have to read a little more.

Comment: Doesn't the electric shock used to stop a heart attack cause dramatic fast stretching of the heart muscles? I'm basically asking is a heart attack like a muscle spasm in the heart muscles?

Comment: Okay. I understand! I'm going to run a couple edits on your question and you can see what you think of them. You can change anything back that you don't like.

Comment: You should be able to find either a review button or some such that will let you see my edits before someone else approves them.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to do some reading and research and I found some interesting information that was a). news to me. And b). the answer is yes... And no.

A spasm can be the cause of a heart attack by causing the coronary artery to contract. When that artery contracts, it causes a dramatic decrease in blood flow to the heart. When the heart looses access to oxygenated blood it can cause chest pain (angina) or even an MI (Myocardial Infarction a.k.a. a heart attack). This spasm is can be caused by exposure to extreme cold, smoking and the use of certain recreational drugs.

However, this type of spasm cannot be stopped with defibrillation. Treatment for these involves administering Nitroglycerin and then later treatment involving Statin drugs and such.

In the terms you are speaking of, I don't see that that would be quite accurate. The most common cause of sudden cardiac death is VF (Ventricular Fibrillation) which is essentially an uncontrollable quivering of the heart muscle. I've never heard this described as a spasm though. Google searches of spasm and heart spasm have all lead to definitions of the word spasm and the coronary artery spasm mentioned above.

However, within that, I think you have a valid point and a decent understanding of how things work, just perhaps not fitting under the definition of a spasm.

When a defibrillator is used, it delivers a measured electrical shock to the person's heart and hopefully stops the chaotic electrical rhythm. I'm not sure if this part is correct however, I do not think you should look at that as a stretching of the muscle though. It is an electrical intervention that interrupts the former rhythm and hopefully the heart "forgets" what it was doing and returns to a sinus rhythm.

**So, to summarize:** A heart attack can be caused by a spasm; however, defibrillation does not help that type of attack. A defibrillator does not 'stretch' the heart but rather interrupts it's former rhythm. Because an irregular heart beat is not considered a spasm, I find it difficult to believe that any form of EMP would help it; however, I would love to hear that it has!

For more information on Ventricular Fibrillation, CAS (Coronary Artery Spasm) and AED's (Automated External Defibrillator(s)). Please see the following:

[MedlinePlus - on V-fib](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/007200.htm)

[The Mayo Clinic - on CAS](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/angina/expert-answers/coronary-artery-spasm/faq-20058316)

[HeartSine - on AED's](http://heartsine.com/2012/12/how-does-an-automated-external-defibrillator-work/)

I hope this was helpful for you!

**Edits:**

In the comments, we had discussed a variety of possible causes and treatments for spasms, as well as what - if any - connection there is between how a spasm in perhaps a leg would be caused as compared to how one in your heart could be caused.

From the reading and research I did, I was fairly inconclusive about the safety or desirability of a device to prevent heart attacks using an EMP device implanted in your brain or on your brain stem.

As far as how similar a spasm in your heart is to a spasm in any other muscle, they are not very similar. As seen [here](http://www.webmd.com/pain-management/muscle-spasms-cramps-charley-horse), a muscle spasm in most parts of the body can be caused by numerous things, such as dehydration, poor blood circulation, mineral deficiencies etc. Whereas a heart spasm (know as a CAS) can be caused by alcohol withdrawal, stimulant use, extreme cold... As seen [here](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/000159.htm).

Comment: Very useful info. I was wondering , when other muscles like a leg muscle has a spasm how are they treated? Could a 'tiny' defibrillator stop a leg muscle spasm?

Comment: Was it Galvani who experimented with a frog's leg and a small charge of electricity? Has anyone tried that experiment with an 'appropriate' electro- magnetic charge?

Comment: @201044 I did find somethings that discussed the use of an electrical pulse to control bladder spasms. [Medicine.net](http://www.medicinenet.com/bladder_spasms/page4.htm).

Comment: The sinus rhythms (if that's what it's called)  that controls the heart pulses ; does this have 'part's' in the brain that regulate this rhythms. If so could electrical pulses effect these rhythms by effecting the associated parts in the brain. So if on had a heart attack maybe the 'relevant' parts in the brain or the spinal chord could be 'zapped' instead of the heart itself.

Comment: @201044 Yes, they are indeed called sinus rhythms. I will do some more reading and see what I find.

Comment: @201044 I did some additional reading on this and it looks like it may or may not be helpful but isn't necessarily dangerous either. (Although in someone suffering a heart attack it could be dangerous, the heart rate slows and then the person's blood pressure goes up). Here are two links you may find helpful, [Johns Hopkins Anatomy of the Brain](http://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/healthlibrary/conditions/nervous_system_disorders/anatomy_of_the_brain_85,P00773/) and [PubMed.gov](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22540399).

Comment: But maybe something similar to a pace maker could detect the precursors to a heart attack and if connected to relevant parts of the brain and / or spinal chord it could 'zap' them with tiny electric stimuli to prevent any subsequent attacks.

Comment: @201044 I'm afraid this has gone beyond my scope of understanding. I will tell you that not all heart attacks are caused by an abnormal rhythm; some can be caused by lack of oxygen due to a blockage or some such. Also, I think that part of the reason this has not previously been done is that it is much safer and easier to implant an AICD (Automated Internal Cardioverter Defibrillator) or pacemaker. Both of which can be implanted in an outpatient procedure. I hope to edit my answer later today.

Comment: Could an implanted device 'attached' to a part of the spinal chord and/or the brain moniter any known precursors to having a heart attack?

Comment: @201044 I think _perhaps_ theoretically that could be done. But I'm just not sure how many people would ever be willing to line up to have the back of their head cut open to have a device implanted that could much more safely be implanted in their chest - near  their collar bone.

Comment: They might if the device prevented any precursors to any susceptibility to an attack.

Comment: @201044 I know at least two people who wouldn't. Myself and my mother... Just sayin' :)

Comment: What causes muscular spasms in any other muscle ,other than the muscles in the heart? Are the causes of a non-heart muscle spasm similar to what might cause a heart muscle spasm?

Comment: @201044 There are a variety of reasons, from diet to medications. I will share a link in my official answer with a list of common causes. The common causes of most muscle spasms are not at all the same as those causing a CAS (Coronary Artery Spasm).

Comment: What can cause a leg muscle spasm?

Comment: @201044 The same things that cause other spasms.

Comment: What is that, specifically that causes spasms?

Comment: @201044 I understand your question now! I'm just having a hard time finding information on it. I'll get back with you if/when I find something!

Comment: @201044 Perhaps that would be a good question to ask as a new question.